.js script inside docker-entrypoint-initdb.d doesn't work
I'm using docker compose to run mongo container and create a user with js script inside docker-entrypoint-initdb.d but when I run "docker compose up mongo " command, the container is up but the user inside js script didn't create. As far as I know, all of the script inside docker-entrypoint-initdb.d is supposed to be created on container up.
This is the folder structure
 Project-directory
 ┣ mongo
 ┃   ┣  docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
 ┃   ┃ ┗  init-ossportal.js
 ┃   ┣ Dockerfile
 ┗  docker-compose.yaml

Dockerfile
ARG MONGO_VERSION=4.0
FROM devdocker-repo.frontiir.net/mongo:${MONGO_VERSION}

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

USER root

ARG TZ=UTC
ENV TZ=${TZ}

RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/${TZ} /etc/localtime && echo ${TZ} > /etc/timezone
RUN set -xe; \
  apt-get update -yqq && \
  apt-get install -yqq \
    xz-utils

ARG MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin
ARG MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=passwd

ENV MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME} \
  MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD}

Docker compose file
version: '3'

services:
  mongo:
    build:
      context: ./mongo
      args:
        - MONGO_VERSION=4.0
        - TZ=Asia/Yangon
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=passwd
    container_name: mongo_4.0
    volumes:
      - ./.data/mongo:/data/db
      - ./mongo/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-ossportal.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-ossportal.js:ro
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    tty: true
    

init-ossportal.js
db = db.getSiblingDB('admin');

// change the `passwd` to MONGO_ROOT_PASSWORD from .env file
db.auth('admin', 'passwd');

// change the database name to your project database
db = db.getSiblingDB('ossportal');

// change to your project database, username and password
db.createUser({
  user: 'ossportal_admin',
  pwd: 'pass',
  roles: [
    { role: 'readWrite', db: 'ossportal' }
  ]
});


Did you do docker compose up before and the data dir already existed? If so, it wont re-execute the init scripts. That only happens when the container is started the first time. Delete your data dir .data/mongo and then re-run up. And keep an eye your docker logs which show when the init scripts are executed, if they are.

Thank you so much aneroid. That's solved my problem.
